# TensorFlow/Keras model __call__ gets slower and slower when run on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement an AlphaZero-like boardgame AI for the game Gomoku (Monte Carlo Tree Search in combination with a CNN that evaluations board positions).

Right now, the MCTS is implemented as a separate component.
Additionally, I have a simple TCP server written in Python that receives positions from the MCTS (in batches of around 50 to 200), converts them to Numpy arrays, passes them to the TF/Keras Model by invoking `__call__`, converts them back, and sends the results to the MCTS via TCP.

During training, I generate training data (around 5000 boards) by having the AI play against itself, call `model.fit` once, create a new dataset using the new model weights and so on.
I play multiple matches in parallel, each using their separate Python/TF server.
Each server loads their own copy of the model (I use `tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)`).

I problem I encounter is that, while playing matches, inference time is getting longer and longer, the longer the network is loaded until it gets so painfully slow that I have to restart the training.
After a restart, inference times are back to normal.
This, by the way, also happens if I only play one game at a time with just having one model loaded.

I tried to mitigate the problem by restarting the Python server (and therefore the model) after each match.
This seemingly solved it until I started experiencing the same issue after a couple of training iterations.

At first I thought the reason was my not ideal setup (gaming notebook running Windows), but on a Linux server of my university the problem also ocured.
On my Windows machine, along with the model getting slower and slower it was also using less and less memory. This apparently did not occur on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was due to having the wrong NVIDIA drivers installed for my card and not having CUDA installed. Hope that was helpful.

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads